# error trying to load the config "relay" for the macro imported from "babel-plugin-relay/macro"

Tags: reactjs, plugins, babeljs, relay

We are trying to upgrade our react project to latest packages including relay (7.0.0).  Our application builds and works but we are getting this error message in the console (during build) on every file where we import graphql from 'babel-plugin-relay/macro'.  We are doing exactly like documented here  [adding relay](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-relay/)

The error is "There was an error trying to load the config "relay" for the macro imported from "babel-plugin-relay/macro. Please see the error thrown for more information."   It is coming from  \node_modules\babel-plugin-macros\dist\index.js in getConfig( ).

To understand how other projects were configured, I downloaded another sample relay project / installed it and it had the same problem.  Interesting enough there was this recent post in that app's issues list [error loading config](https://github.com/relayjs/relay-examples/issues/120)

The solution noted worked for me (adding that noted .babel-plugin-macrosrc.yml file with empty relay plugin?) but I am not understanding why this is needed or what was causing this seemingly benign error message?